# Date before method returns false if both dates are equal

Tags: java, date

When comparing two dates with date `before` method, if the dates are similar, it returns false as follows:

- **date1: Tue Dec 18 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2012**
- **date2: Tue Dec 18 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2012**

the method `date1.before(date2)` always returns `false` in this case, which does not make sense to me (doesn't apply to my case in other words).
I want to check if a date (day/month/year) equals today's date (day/month/year)?

Comment: imho it makes total sense. If two things happen at the same time, than neither of both happened before the other.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Ummm, unless I'm missing something, these two dates appear to be equal, so date1.before(date2) should return false.

Comment: date1 being before date2 implies that date2 is not before date1, so what you are suggesting is itself a contradiction

Comment: Are you using `java.util.Date`? While this made sense to do 11 years ago when the question was asked, the recommendation today is clear: do not use that class. It was always poorly designed and is long outdated. Depending on context and exact requirements you will probably want to use `Instant` or perhaps `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime`. They are all from [java.time, the modern java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). It will still be true that an `Instant` is not before itself, though.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

As `date1.equals(date2)`, it is normal that `date1.before(date2)` returns `false`. As will do `date1.after(date2)`.

Both dates are the same, so one is not before the other.

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) :

> true if and only if the instant of time represented by this Date
> object is **strictly** earlier than the instant represented by when;
> false otherwise.

Try something like:

```
if (date1.before(date2) || date1.equals(date2)) ...
```

The answers provided below suggest testing for the inverse, and they're right:

```
if (!date1.after(date2)) ...
```

Both tests are equivalent.

Comment: I think @taswyn and bowmore's solutions are better.

Comment: It would be great for Oracle to develop a new method with signature date1.equalsOrBefore(date2) to help developers reduce conditions.

Answer (score 66):

You can simply test the inverse :

```
!date1.after(date2)
```

You can always convert a strict order check to a non-strict check in this manner. Since mathematically :

```
a > b ⇔ ¬ (a ≤ b)
```

Answer (score 9):

If the dates are equal, then obviously one is NOT before the other: `false is the correct return for date1.before(date2) where date1 == date2`.

If you need to *include* equality, why not do a negation on `.after()` (obviously if date 1 is NOT after date 2, then it is *equal or before*), but I would make sure that this is actually correct logic for what you are trying to accomplish.

If equality is a special case that needs to be handled differently, then have a separate test for `.equals()`.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the inverse like it was proposed by bowmore: `!date1.after(date2)`

Or if you are looking for ranges, between can include the endpoints, in which case you could `use return !d.before(min) && !d.after(max)`

Answer (score 6):

You can use this also:

```
boolean check = dateOne.before(dateTwo) || DateUtils.isSameDay(dateOne, dateTwo);
```

DateUtils is from **org.apache.commons.lang.time** package

Answer (score 3):

The real problem with your code maybe is that you are not taking into account the millis and the before function does

Two objects java.util.Date with a toString result: Sun Aug 28 00:00:00 CEST 2016
may have a different value when calling to getTime.
For instance

```
Date d1;
Date d2;
d1.toString(); // = Sun Aug 28 00:00:00 CEST 2016
d2.toString(); // = Sun Aug 28 00:00:00 CEST 2016
d1.getTime(); // = 1472335200605
d2.getTime(); // = 1472335200000
```

Of course, these dates are not equals.

> ### From javadoc:
>
> "Returns:true if and only if the instant of time represented by this Date object is strictly earlier than the instant represented by when; false otherwise."

Comment: Good answer. For a more detailed and accurate default String output, convert to an [`java.time.Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). `myUtilDate.toInstant().toString()` → `2016-08-27T22:00:00.605Z`. Or, `Instant.ofEpochMilli ( 1_472_335_200_605L )`

Comment: Yes, if you are working in Java 8 is recommended using Instant and the bunch of new classes to manage dates.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a normal behavior because `dateBefore` checks whether one date is **before** the other one. If the dates are equal this is obvious to be false.

Answer (score 1):

Assertj's [isBeforeOrEqualTo](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-joda-time/latest/org/assertj/jodatime/api/LocalDateAssert.html#isBeforeOrEqualTo-org.joda.time.LocalDate-) is an option for tests.

Examle for `Instant` taken from the [doc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractDateAssert.html#isAfterOrEqualTo(java.time.Instant)):

```
// assertions succeed
// theTwoTowers release date : 2002-12-18
assertThat(theTwoTowers.getReleaseDate()).assertIsAfterOrEqualTo(Instant.parse("2002-12-17T00:00:00.00Z"))
                                         .assertIsAfterOrEqualTo(Instant.parse("2002-12-18T00:00:00.00Z"));
// assertion fails
assertThat(theTwoTowers.getReleaseDate()).assertIsAfterOrEqualTo(Instant.parse("2002-12-19T00:00:00.00Z"));
```

Comment: According to your link that works with Joda-Time’s `LocalDate`. The Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode and not recommended for new code. Use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). Do you know if a newer version of AssertJ exists that supports java.time in the same way? If so, this seems to me to be a very good solution.

Comment: java.time.Instant is available. Please check [API](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractDateAssert.html#isAfterOrEqualTo(java.time.Instant))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answers from 2012 are correct and were generally good answers back then. Nowadays we surely prefer to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, over the `Date` class implied in the question. `Date` is poorly designed and now long outdated.

The two recommended ways to obtain a “before or equal” comparison are:

1. **The natural and wordy** one:

   ```
       OffsetDateTime dateTime1 = OffsetDateTime.of(2012, 12, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));
       OffsetDateTime dateTime2 = OffsetDateTime.of(2012, 12, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));

       if (dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2) || dateTime1.isEqual(dateTime2)) {
           System.out.println("dateTime1 is before or equal to dateTime2");
       } else {
           System.out.println("dateTime1 is after dateTime2");
       }
   ```

   Output is:

   > dateTime1 is before or equal to dateTime2

   As an aside `OffsetDateTime.isEqual()` compares points in time, instants, across UTC offsets and will return true of the two objects denote the same point in time. Also `isBefore()` works across different UTC offsets.
2. **The brief one** where we reverse the condition:

   ```
       if (dateTime1.isAfter(dateTime2)) {
           System.out.println("dateTime1 is after dateTime2");
       } else {
           System.out.println("dateTime1 is before or equal to dateTime2");
       }
   ```

   Output is the same as before.

Depending on requirements you could easily find yourself preferring the `Instant` class over `OffsetDateTime`. The `if` condition will be the same.

No matter if using the old-fashioned `Date` or one of the modern classes *before* means *strictly before*. So to obtain *before or equal* we need to use one of the variants above.